# How to use default user properties with firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

I've read on the doc that firebase uses the Android Advertising ID or Apple IDFA to get demographics (age, gender) however this information doesn't show up in the analytics.

Is there some additional steps that need to be done in order to activate or link these informations to the Analytics? I'm currently using some custom userProperties but it would be good to know why the default ones doesn't work.

Comment: Can you specify which information you want to see in analytics? Demographic data or ADID/IDFA? Are you also talking about BigQuery or Firebase UI?

Comment: Yup, I was talking about the default age and gender properties, I'm using firebase UI at the moment. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two places to check for demographics data:

1. Analytics > Audiences section, what you probably want here is the audience that should be automatically created - "All users".
2. Events > go into any event detail.

In both cases you should see location, gender, age. Also have in mind that because of privacy reasons

- you need at least a few users (I think the limit is 10) for some of this data to be shown, so it might not show up in small test project
- This data doesn't get exported to BigQuery at all - because then you could identify it with a particular user